# Need to detect particular icon in the image given using openCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In the below input image I need to detect the highlighted icons using openCV in python. The biggest challenge here is the icon to be detected are rotation variant which means they can be rotated in any direction. But still the algorithm needs to detect as shown below. I tried with template matching but it wasn't able to detect properly. I am newbie to image processing so any ideas/thought will be very much helpful.

Comment: Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I would suggest doing edge extraction and then use shape matching. See cv2.matchShapes() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaadc90cb16e2362c9bd6e7363e6e4c317 and https://learnopencv.com/shape-matching-using-hu-moments-c-python/